# Cannot retrieve data from database using first() method

Tags: php, laravel

I have this routing:

```
Route::get('/item/{item_id?}',['uses'=>'ItemController@get_item_view']);
```

I want to redirect to the first item if no item ID is given.

```
  public function get_item_view($id = null)
    {


        if($id == null)
        {
#This doesnt work
            $selected_item = Item::where('item_id',Auth::user()->item_id)->first();
        }
        else
        {
#This works
        $selected_item = Item::where('id',$id)
            ->where('item_id',Auth::user()->item_id)
            ->first();
        }
        if($selected_item === null)
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }


        return view('auth.forms.item')->with('item',$selected_item);
    }
```

If I introduce an ID (www.myproject.com/item/2), the page works perfectly, but if I don't, and try to get just the first of the list just to generate the page. I expect www.myproject.com/item to give me the first item.

This is the error I get:

> Trying to get property of non-object (View:
>   /var/www/myproject/resources/views/auth/forms/item.blade.php)

and when I use `dd($selected_item)` on both cases I get the same type of object. I have no idea why one is working and the other one isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't provide item id then it'll be null,

```
$selected_item = Item::where('item_id',null)->first();
```

if you want to list first item just do

```
if($id == null)
        {
#This doesnt work
            $selected_item = Item::all()->first();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `Auth::user()->item_id` has a value. the error seems to be generating from it.

you can do `dd(Auth::user()->item_id)` to check it